# Check range of integer in a custom control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I want to create a CustomControl. I have a `Maximum` and a `Minimum` and a `LowerValue`. I want to limit the numbers of `LowerValue` to the possible values between `Minimum` and `Maximum`.

```
[DefaultValue(100)]
public int Maximum { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(0)]
public int Minimum { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(0)]
public int LowerValue { get; set; }
```

`LowerValue` should be between 0..100. I want it like if you type a wrong number in `Value` of a TrackBar and it says "Invalid Property Value".

I tried this:

```
private int _lowerValue;
[DefaultValue(0)]
public int LowerValue {
  get {
    return _lowerValue;
  }
  set {
    if (value < Minimum)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid value. Value must be between " + Minimum.ToString() + " and "+Maximum.ToString());
    else
      _lowerValue = value;
  }
}
```

When i put a UserControl with this code in my Form, Visual Studio crashes.

So how can i do that?

Comment: And what Visual Studio says when it crashes?

Comment: Nothing... "has encountered a problem and needs to close", search for solution of the problem, restart.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code. I've tried this in both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 and I get a dialog that says "Property value is not valid." and not a crash, which is what I would expect. It suggests to me that there's a configuration issue with Visual Studio. I would try a repair/reinstall.

Comment: I agree with @DanStevens.  Sounds like your Visual Studio is corrupted.

Comment: @AndrewQuaschnick and DanStevens: even with my edit? It worked the last 2 hours without any crash after i did this.

Comment: @fedab If you fixed it. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it: first i used the property without a variable:

```
public int LowerValue {
  get { return LowerValue; }
  set { if(valid) LowerValue = value; }
}
```

That's not the best idea because i in the set i call the set again and have an infinite loop.

--> Visual Studio crash

I changed it to the code i posted above, but it also crashed. I thought my new code was also wrong but the only problem was that i didn't created a new solution after i fixed it.

After that all worked. There was nothing wrong with the code.